# Swift - Formatting an Array of Phone Number Strings

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I have an array of phonenumbers from my phone's contacts list that are are in different formats ranging from +1 (123) 123-1234, 1231231234, +11231231234, and 123-123-1234.  I want them to all be in the format of 1231231234, but I don't much about string formatting.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
var phoneNumberDigits = ""

for character in phoneNumber.unicodeScalars {
    if digits.longCharacterIsMember(character.value) {
        phoneNumberDigits += String(character)
    }
}
```